# Heroku not listing pg_search_documents table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, pg-search

This is pretty weird but for some reason, heroku doesn't seem to show the `pg_search_documents` table when when I list tables using the [heroku-sql-console](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console).

```
>> heroku sql

SQL> show tables
+------------------------+
|       table_name       |
+------------------------+
| activity_notifications |
| attachments            |
| businesses             |
| color_modes            |
| comments               |
| counties               |
| customer_employees     |
| customers              |
| delayed_jobs           |
| file_imports           |
| invitations            |
| invoices               |
| jobs                   |
| paper_stocks           |
| paper_weights          |
| quotes                 |
| rails_admin_histories  |
| schema_migrations      |
| tax_rates              |
| users                  |
+------------------------+
```

As you can see, no mention of pg_search.

Then, in the same session,

```
SQL> select * from pg_search_documents;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |       content       | searchable_id | searchable_type  |        created_at         |        updated_at         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  3 | Energy Centre       |             3 | Customer         | 2012-12-03 19:33:55 -0800 | 2012-12-03 19:33:55 -0800 |

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It's also interesting that the `show tables` command lists only 20 tables whereas `heroku pg:info` says there are 21.

The reason this is a problem rather than a curiosity is because I can't get `heroku db:pull` to pull down the `pg_search_documents` table (everything else pulls fine) and I can't test migrations on production data.

I'm using `PG Version:  9.1.6` on heroku and `PostgreSQL 9.2.1` locally. Also PgSearch 0.5.7.

Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: I should add heroku-sql-console to the deprecated list. What happens if you use `heroku pg:psql` then run \d ?

Comment: ok yeah now that plugin is deprecated

Comment: Yeah if I run `\d` with `pg:psql` then I can see the table in the list. It's still missing when I `db:pull` though.

Comment: that's because db:pull (TAPS) is also super terrible and awful. use pgbackups. friends don't let friends use taps.